# Attempting to nest an IF ELSE into an IF EXIST in cmd.exe

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd

This is the code that I have:

```
IF EXIST %CD%\tictactoeXwinlog.log (
  ECHO %xwinlog% > tictactoeXwinlog.log
  ) ELSE (
    IF %xwinlog% > 0 (
ECHO %xwinlog% > %CD%\tictactoeXwinlog.log
) ELSE (
  ECHO 0 > %CD%\tictactoeXwinlog.log
  )
```

What I'm trying to do in plain English is have it check to see if the log file exists. If it does, then write the current value of the variable %xwinlog% to the log, overwriting anything there. If it does NOT exist, I want it to ensure that the variable's value is higher than 0, and if so, write that to the log file, if not higher than zero, then write zero to the log file. The last part is because for whatever reason, when it tries to write the variable to the log and the variable is 0, it instead writes "ECHO is off"

What I'm getting is an error saying ") is unexpected at this time"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should note that `%CD%` is always replaced by the **current directory**; this mean that `%CD%\filename.ext` is _exactly the same_ than just `filename.ext`, so the former form is customarily never used...

Answer (score 3):

1. Missing closed paren as pointed out by Alex is one problem.
2. Another problem is that > is a redirection symbol.  Use GTR to do an arithmetic comparison.
3. Use quotes around an expression like "%CD%\tictactoeXwinlog.log" when used in a comparison in case there are spaces in %CD%.
4. I think your problem that caused you to have to "check for 0" was really that xwinlog was blank, which resulted in the echo statement displaying the ECHO state (on/off).  That is why I always use
   ECHO.
   Some people use
   ECHO:
5. If xwinlog is a numeric value, then your code can be simplified to:

   ```
   IF NOT %xwinlog% gtr 0 SET xwinlog=0
   ECHO %xwinlog% > tictactoeXwinlog.log
   ```
6. If winlog is a string value, then you code can be simplified to:

   ```
   IF "%xwinlog%"=="" SET xwinlog=0 or Any string of your choice... like Not Found
   ECHO %xwinlog% > tictactoeXwinlog.log
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Missing parenthesis I guess.

```
IF EXIST %CD%\tictactoeXwinlog.log (
  ECHO %xwinlog% > tictactoeXwinlog.log
) ELSE (
  IF %xwinlog% > 0 (
    ECHO %xwinlog% > %CD%\tictactoeXwinlog.log
   ) ELSE (
     ECHO 0 > %CD%\tictactoeXwinlog.log
   )
)
```